# Redirect domain to subfolder, from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My friend's dad asked me to change the design of his website, so he gave me access to his account and I created a sub-folder where I uploaded the new design. The problem is that he has forgotten the password to his control panel and I only have access to the FTP in the sub-folder. I'm trying to redirect the domain (currently going to the root folder) to the sub-folder but since I don't have access to the root folder I'm finding it difficult to do so.

I've already tried a redirect with .htaccess but since I can only upload the file to my sub-folder, it thinks the redirect is to a sub-folder within that folder, instead of the folder inside the root.

TL;DR...
I want to redirect 'mydomain.com' to 'mydomain.com/folder' but only have access to the FTP in 'mydomain.com/folder'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like he’ll have to reset his control panel password…

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon, see below (but he *should* reset his password, anyway).

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the /etc/passwd file???

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I don't, I only have direct access to the sub-folder. I'm thinking he will have to change his password, doesn't help that his host service is provided by a local phone company and it has the most complicated control panel I have ever seen, a total mess to be honest.

Comment: Honore doctor undelete answer i was going to suggest you an edit if you want

Comment: Just change the password... It will be the better solution. Anyway if doctor undeletes answer I will suggest him an edit

Comment: @Alejandro, done, but I was looking at the problem backwards (redirecting from his new directory *to* the existing directory, not existing → new).

Answer (score 1):

[.htaccess applies to the directory that contains it.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess)

You cannot change this if you have not access to vhost.conf files (what would change the base dir of the site) or to the parent directory’s .htaccess.

You will need to:

- Reset your dad’s friend’s password and forget this redirect, changing the existing web files (the cleanest way), or
- change the .htaccess file in your parent's dad directory, adding this:

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ dir2/$1 [R=301,L,P]

This should redirect the user to dir2, hiding that redirect in the urlbar.

*h/t @Alejandro Teixeira Muñoz for the edits!*

Comment: but without access to the parent .htaccess it will not be possible at first. Maybe ssh access is still possible..

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't do anything with the domain, it just made the sub-folder load slower for some reason

Comment: This works because we’ve set the `RewriteBase` to the root directory, dir1 & dir2’s parent. mod_rewrite automatically strips `dir1/` off of the url because this .htaccess is in dir1… so we can prepend `dir2/` to the url and we’re good to go. (It surprised me, too!)

Comment: D’oh, I just realized that you only have access to dir2, and do need to redirect from the web server’s root! Disregard.

Comment: I’ve incorporated @Alejandro’s edits, thx for that Alejandro.